# How do I list all commands in GNU info?

Tags: info

When I run `info info`, I get the following text at the top.

```
File: dir,      Node: Top,      This is the top of the INFO tree.

This is the Info main menu (aka directory node).
A few useful Info commands:

  'q' quits;
  '?' lists all Info commands;
  'h' starts the Info tutorial;
  'mTexinfo RET' visits the Texinfo manual, etc.
```

If I then type `?`, I expect to see all the Info commands, but instead, I get the following at the bottom of my screen.

```
Regexp search backward:
```

**How do I actually list all commands in info?**

Comment: When I type `?`, I get this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NcJXNRsbt6/ with, the bottom half a looooooooooooong, scrollable list of commands.

Comment: are you sure the keyboard keys (ctrl, alt, shift ) is not locked and pressed

Comment: Using `info 6.3` I should type `H` to list all command , the `?` give me `Regexp search backward: `

Comment: @GAD3R, I'm using `info 6.1` and it looks like `H` also does what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Kamaraj, Yes, I'm sure that `Shift` is pressed. On my keyboard, that's the only way to type `?`.

Comment: @GAD3R, Where did you find `H`? It looks like `h` takes me to the `man info` page, rather than a tutorial, so I'd like to know where the authoritative source is for our versions of `info`.

Comment: From the `info info` : `'H' lists all Info commands;`